# CSS media query for all phones but not iPad

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi I'm trying to write a media query that will affect all phones but not iPads.

I'm having a hard time doing so because apparently android devices change their device-width as they change orientation.  Portrait to Landscape means the width becomes the height and vice versa.  Apple devices report their device width as the same value regardless of orientation.  The fact that there are android phones with higher resolution than iPads further complicates the issue.

If there is an android phone with a device height of 1280px and iPads have a device height of 1024px, how can I write a media query that will affect all Android phones but not iPads?

Comment: are there android devices with pixel-ratio:2? perhaps you could query another attribute in conjunction with size

Comment: There are android devices with pixel-ratio 2 and this would be a solution for those devices.  However there are are android phones with a resolution greater than that of an iPad that have a pixel-ratio: 1 and they would not be accounted for with this solution.

Comment: and I'm now realizing that wouldn't even help on iPad2 which doesn't have retina

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to differentiate an Android device in landscape from an iPad in landscape, but I'm not sure on portrait:

```
<style>
@media all and (min-device-aspect-ratio:1/1) and (orientation:landscape) {
    /*because an iPad doesn't change it's width, it's device aspect ratio will not be greater than 1/1  */
    body {background-color:#00FF00;}
}
</style>
```